# Selection change in Tree Map in High Chart

Tags: javascript, performance, highcharts, treemap

jsfiddle link : [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/surajcs009/b0tbL83b/)

There are two issues needs to be resolved here:

Issue 1: 
Clicking on selection2 and selection 3 is working fine but clicking back on Selection1 does not reflect the changes.

Issue 2: 
To return different dataLabel for different selections, I have written the code, and it seems to be working fine but while debugging I found that everytime a selection is made, following code is executed twice.

```
formatter: function () {
  if(value=="selection3"){
    return '<b>'+this.point.name + '<br/>'+ this.point.value + '%</b> ' 
  }else{
    return '<b>'+this.point.name + '<br/>'+ this.point.value + '</b> '
  }
},
```

My question is how this formatter function works and why the if condition is executed twice for each selection.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Issue one is caused by `selection1Data` being set in the initialization, and updated by reference. That is, when you press selection 2, `selection1Data` is updated to the values of selection 2, so now, `selection1Data = selection2Data`. And therefore pressing selection 1 gives no difference. You can see this if you set breakpoints in your update functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**According Issue 1:**

As @ewolden mentioned

> Issue one is caused by selection1Data being set in the initialization, and updated by reference

to fix it you can use `setData(data [, redraw] [, animation] [, updatePoints])` method to update your data with `updatePoints` set to `false` (For all series changes)

```
$('#selection1').click(function() {
  value = "selection1";
  chart.series[0].setData(selection1Data, true, {}, false);
});
```

> **updatePoints** (Default: **true**)
>
> When the updated data is the same length as the existing data, points will be updated instead of replaced. This allows updating with animation and performs better. In this case, the original array is not passed by reference. Set false to prevent.

also using `setData` more preferable than `update`

> .. `**[update]**` method  is more performance expensive than some other utility methods like Highcharts.Series#setData or Highcharts.Series#setVisible.

---

**According Issue 2:**

Function `formatter` will be called for each series which will be provided. In your example `chart` contains two series and that cause why

> ... everytime a selection is made, following code is executed twice.